# No grouped items on OrderRepositoryInterface

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I try to get all products items from *Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface* but i get simples products instead of grouped product. Everything is right with configurables

```
$criteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
            ->addFilter('created_at', $from, 'gteq')
            ->addFilter('created_at', $to, 'lteq')
            ->addFilter('store_id', $storeId,'eq')
            ->addFilter('status', $status,'eq')
            ->create();

$orderResult = $this->orderRepository->getList($criteria);

$orders = $orderResult->getItems();
```

and then i get items with

```
        foreach ($orders as $order) {

            $items = $order->getItems();
        }
```

same result with *getAllVisibleItems()*

also on database there are only simple products however, indicated as grouped

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I find a workaround like this

```
if ($item->getProductType() === 'grouped'){ $options = $item->getProductOptions(); }
```

take a look at this value

```
$options['info_buyRequest']['super_product_config']["product_id"]
```